Using mailcow-dockerize send emails without authentication
My mail server is Mailcow-dockerize.
I have 20 accounts and sending and receiving working file.
Now I have a case that my one system need to send mail without authentication.
“app-svr@domain.tld” need to send without authentication to “noc@domain.tld”
How to do this?
